# How to convert SVG CSS animation to pure JS code

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animate

I would like to convert an svg path animation, to a pure javascript one.

SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
</svg>
```

CSS code:

```
.path {
    stroke-dasharray: 10 10;    /* 10px fill, 10px gap */
    -webkit-animation: dash 10s linear normal infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLekbar4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need pure javascript, also this answer may not fit your needs as it actually does create inline CSS. But here it is, mostly taken from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset

```js
function dashOffset() {
    var path = document.querySelector('.path');
    var length = "1000";
    // Clear any previous transition 
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
    // Set up the starting positions 
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "10 10";
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = "1000";
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser 
    // picks up the starting position before animating 
    path.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition 
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 10s linear';
    //listener to restart our loop
    path.addEventListener('transitionend', dashOffset, false);
    // Go! 
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}
dashOffset();
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z" />
</svg>
```

There is also the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) way :

```
function anim(){
    var path = document.querySelector('.path');
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "10 10";
    path.style.strokeDashoffset--;
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    }
requestAnimationFrame(anim);
```

```js
function anim(){
        var path = document.querySelector('.path');
        path.style.strokeDasharray = "10 10";
        path.style.strokeDashoffset--;
        requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }
 requestAnimationFrame(anim);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z" />
</svg>
```

Note that you may be able to reproduce it with the pure SVG [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion) element.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you give a try to the Raphael.js library.

Using it you could easily reproduce what you want.

Additionally there's this very useful tool to convert your SVG file into Raphael.js reusable code : http://www.readysetraphael.com/

So your SVG file will become :

```
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '340', '333');

var path_a = rsr.path("M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z");

path_a.attr({
  class: 'path',
  fill: '#FFFFFF',
  stroke: '#000000',
  "stroke-width": '4',
  "stroke-miterlimit": '10',
  'stroke-opacity': '1' 
}).data('id', 'path_a');

var rsrGroups = [];
```

Then you just have to add a `<div id="rsr"></div>` to your document and also replace the CSS selector `.path` to `path`.

Et voilà !

Check this Fiddle to see the it in action : 
http://jsfiddle.net/47nkqgmn/

Comment: Using Raphael is not pure JS and fiddle is not working.

Comment: Ah sorry, this fiddle was working for me but I missed the Save button.
I've updated my answer with a new link. Also as Scott said, RaphaelJS is a library entirely written in pure Javascript. No dependencies are needed but perhaps you are not working in a browser. If the context you are in is for example a WebView in a mobile application so the Kaiido should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few javascript SVG libraries you could look into.  I'm partial to Raphael (www.raphaeljs.com).

It would be something like this:

```
var paper = Raphael('canvas', 600, 600);
paper.path("M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-    5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z")
.attr({fill:"#FFFFFF", stroke: "#000000", "stroke-width": "4", "stroke-miterlimit": "10"})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLekbar4/

(Note: I added a div to the html as a container for the raphael "canvas", and changed the css to apply to 'path' elements, instead of elements with class '.path')

Comment: Using Raphael is not pure JS.

Comment: Excuse me, but yes it is. It is a solution written entirely in Javascript.  If you don't want to use a library, then you could rebuild the svg html you have using javascript.  This is effectively what the library does, but if you insist.